# Control polymer element Rendering

Tags: javascript, performance, polymer

Is it possible to control the rendering of an element in polymer? I do have multiple paper-tabs and I want to render only the visible content first and after that render it in the background or render it on visible. I want to optimize that, because I have a lot of elements in every tab and the rendering performance is not so good.

I'm using the latest polymer version 1.7

Edit: The hidden attribute of the web component doesn't effect the rendering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some ways in which you can achieve this

- Include elements of each tab inside a `dom-if` and make `dom-if` true only when tab is selected
- Move all the elements/UI inside each tab into a new element and lazy load those elements only when tab is selected. You can lazy load elements using [importHref](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/instance-methods#imports-and-urls)

Comment: This is what I did. I created a custom component, which adds with lazy loading the content into the tab.